# how to add a job in existing job sql server agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

how to add an new job into existing job in sql server agent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sp_start_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) to start another SQL Agent job.

Add a new Step to an existing job:

- Database: msdb
- Command: `EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Batch Job B';` (Name of 2nd SQL Agent Job)

---

[image: New Job Step]